# Unable to successfully apply/run Kentico hotfix 12.0.29

Tags: kentico, hotfix

We develop a site using Kentico 12 MVC with the CMS Ultimate and have been applying hotfixes fine all the way to 12.0.28.

I then tried multiple times to apply hotfix 12.0.29 and it failed with the same errors, which I was able to reproduce. After applying all hotfix steps, the last rebuild is where it fails with the following error list (screenshot attached below):

```
    Error   CS2001  Source file 'C:\GIT\IPG-Laser-Systems\Kentico12\CMS\CMSWebParts\DancingGoat.Samples\DancingGoatSmartSearchAzure.ascx.cs' could not be found.    CMSApp  C:\GIT\IPG-Laser-Systems\Kentico12\CMS\CSC  1   Active

    Error   CS2001  Source file 'C:\GIT\IPG-Laser-Systems\Kentico12\CMS\CMSWebParts\DancingGoat.Samples\DancingGoatSmartSearchAzure.ascx.designer.cs' could not be found.   CMSApp  C:\GIT\IPG-Laser-Systems\Kentico12\CMS\CSC  1   Active

    Error   CS2001  Source file 'C:\GIT\IPG-Laser-Systems\Kentico12\CMS\CMSWebParts\DancingGoat.Samples\DancingGoatConsents.ascx.cs' could not be found.    CMSApp  C:\GIT\IPG-Laser-Systems\Kentico12\CMS\CSC  1   Active

    Error   CS2001  Source file 'C:\GIT\IPG-Laser-Systems\Kentico12\CMS\CMSWebParts\DancingGoat.Samples\DancingGoatConsents.ascx.designer.cs' could not be found.   CMSApp  C:\GIT\IPG-Laser-Systems\Kentico12\CMS\CSC  1   Active
```

Screenshot of build errors

[image]

I follow the step-by-step from these Kentico article [instructions](https://docs.kentico.com/k12sp/installation/hotfix-instructions-kentico-12).

Here are the steps to reproduce the same error:

1. I confirm that my Kentico MVC site is running successfully with 12.0.28.
2. I run the Hotfix_12_0_29.exe installation following the wizard steps.
3. I update the NuGet packages for Kentico to 12.0.29.
4. At this point all good.
5. I run rebuild on Visual Studio and that's where it throws the errors.

### Other things I tried

Based on the error, it's complaining about the missing DancingGoat samples files that the hotfix 12.0.29 installer fail to generate. If I inspect the directory path from the error:

```
C:\GIT\IPG-Laser-Systems\Kentico12\CMS\CMSWebParts\DancingGoat.Samples\
```

The directory is empty, so here are all the things I did and it still failed with another type of error message:

1. My previous backup running under 12.0.28 has those missing sample files, I copy them over into the 12.0.29 installation directory and run rebuild. It throws another list of errors.
2. I created/install a new DancingGoat site and copy over those samples files into the 12.0.29 installation directory and run rebuild. It throws another list of errors.
3. I created/install a new empty site and also tried the same thing as above and it throws another list of errors.
4. I tried applying the hotfix 12.0.30 and those samples files are still missing and complaining about the same errors

All those other tries I did, throw the same type of error, which is attached:

Screenshot of build errors after trying to use samples files from other installations

[image]

There are features that we need, which are available in 12.0.29.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the question author)*.

I was able to successfully apply the hotfix 12.0.29 and also 12.0.30 with the troubleshooting steps I received from Kentico support team via email, which I also contacted them about.

Here are the instructions they gave me:

> There are a few things we can try here, as there has been some previous cases with similar issues.
>
> 1. Make sure to update your MVC project's Kentico.AspNet.Mvc NuGet package to 12.0.29
> 2. Restart both applications, Admin and backend.
> 3. If all nuget packages are updated to the current 12.0.29 and you're still getting these errors upon rebuild, you can try the following:
>
>    - Removing all the nuget kentico packages then reinstalling them.
>    - Clear restart the web app & app pool in IIS.
>    - Then rebuild all web apps again.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before. To work around it, I checked the upgrade log and verified that the error occurred after the file updates and the SQL update. The upgrade was in the compilation step.

I opened the solution in VS and removed those 4 files from the project, and compiled.  Afterwards, Kentico loaded fine, and the version number was correct in the UI and in the DB.